# MariaDB SPIDER engine

Tags: mariadb, spider

I am trying to include just one table from another MariaDB server (lets call it `A`) into the database on another (even physical) server (lets call it `B`). And I came up with the conclusion that `SPIDER` engine might be a good option. But I can't make it work. Here is what I did so far:

**on server `A`**

- I installed the SPIDER engine even though I don't think it is necessary
- Port 3306 is visible from outside
- MariaDB is configured to allow connections from everywhere
- I've created a user `test_user` with host set to `%`
- I've created the following table in the `test` database:

  CREATE TABLE sss (
     id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
     name VARCHAR(50)
  ) ENGINE=InnoDB;

**on server B**

- I installed the SPIDER engine
- I've created the following `SERVER`:

  CREATE SERVER dataNode1 FOREIGN DATA WRAPPER mysql
  OPTIONS (
     HOST 'IP-server-A',
     DATABASE 'test',
     USER 'test_user',
     PASSWORD 'passwd',
     PORT 3306);
- Then I created the table as follows:

  CREATE TABLE sss (
     id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
     name VARCHAR(50)
  ) ENGINE=Spider
  COMMENT='wrapper "mysql", srv "dataNode1", table "sss"';

I manage to connect with `test_user` from `server B` to `server A`:

```
mysql -h IP-server-A -u test_user -ppasswd
```

But when I log with root to `MariaDB` on `server B` and I try to access the table `sss`, I get:

```
#1227 - Access denied; you need (at least one of) the SUPER privilege(s) for this operation
```

What have I missed? Thank you.

Comment: Which MariaDB versions are you using on server A and B? I've just tested this with two MariaDB instances running on the same server, and had no problems making it work. Instead of using the wrapper/server, you can also try specifying the connection details directly in the local table (i.e. on server B) with `COMMENT 'host "IP-server-A", database "test", user "test_user", password "passwd", port "3306"';`

Comment: What are the grants for `test_user` on server A? You can connect as this user to server A, but can you also see the table contents?

Comment: @dbdemon The MariaDB on server A is 10.3.15 and the one on server B is 10.2.8. I've also tried putting the connection params in the COMMENT of the table but still same problem.The grants of `test_user` on server A are ALL PRIVILEGES for the `test` database. I am managing to do `SELECT` with this user on the `sss` table. So, I still have no clue what is going on.